# Does the function y = at^b * exp(-ct) have a name? Can it be linearized? How can I estimate a, b, c?

Tags: r, nlme

I am trying to fit a non-linear model, but can not find any good examples 
online.

Does this function have a name?

Can it be linearized?

I've attempted to estimate the parameters `a`, `b`, and `c` with a random effect `g` (as in group) as a function of time `t`, below. I can fit the model using `nls` without a random effect, but am having trouble getting the model to converge. Suggestions welcome (preferably within R, but any suitable package will do)?

```
## time, repeated 16 times for 4 replicates from each of 4 groups  
t <- rep(1:20, 16)
## g, group
g <- rep(1:4, each = 80)

## starting to create an example dataset, 
## to see if I can recover known parameters
a <- rep(c(3.5, 4, 4.1, 5), each = 80)
b <- rep(c(1.1, 1.4, 1.8, 2.5), each = 80)
c <- rep(c(0.125, 0.25), each = 160)

## error to add to above parameters
set.seed(1)
e_a <- runif(320, -0.5, 0.5)
e_b <- runif(320, -0.1, -0.1)
e_c <- runif(320, -0.02, 0.02)

## this is my function

f <- function(t, a, b, c) a * (t^b) * exp(-c * t)

## simulate y
y <- f(t = t, a + e_a, b + e_b, c + e_c)

mydata <- data.frame(t = t, y = y, g = g)

library(nlme)
## now fit the model to estimate a, b, c
fm1 <- nlme(y ~ a * (t^b) * exp(-c * t),
            data = mydata,
            fixed = a + b + c~1,
            random = a + b + c ~ 1|g,
            start = c(a = 4, b = 1, c = 0.25),
            method = "REML")
```

Comment: Nonlinear least squares is a popular approach to this problem, and covered extensively on this forum. Please refer to the archives.

Comment: @user777 nls seems covered well, less so with random effects. Could you please point me to examples?

Comment: for reproducibility you should tell us where the `ricker()` function comes from ... I would say this is a StackOverflow question (you know what model you want to fit, you're just having computational difficulties fitting it)

Comment: I would probably start by fitting `log(y) ~ log(t) + t` as a linear model (this is Wilkinson-Rogers notation, so it implies $Y \sim LN(\beta_0 + \beta_1 \log(t) + \beta_2 t)$, with parameters corresponding to log(a), b, c ...

Comment: PS I would call this a "generalized Ricker" or possibly "generalized Gamma" (the latter is usually used for distributions, not time series).

Comment: PPS I can make this model converge with `lme4`, but you should be warned that trying to fit 3 or 4 random-effects parameters across only 4 groups is really, really dicey ...

Comment: @BenBolker thanks for the feedback. I had come across different formulations of the Ricker model on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricker_model) and [in your book](http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/emdbook/chap3A.pdf) but wasn't sure if this was the same; it also seems to be very restricted in its domain of application (fisheries, populations), so I was looking for a more general name so that I could find more about its use / application. I've named the function `f`; I've edited the question to define and then use `f()`.

Answer (score 9):

In physics (and some other areas) I've seen this or variants of it called a Hoerl curve or Hoerl function [e.g. here](http://www.2dcurves.com/exponential/exponentialho.html), though it has other names. If *c* is negative and *a* and *b* are positive it's a scaled gamma density.

When you ask about linearizing it, you have to be careful; the equation *y* = *at*^*b* . exp(*ct*) is not actually what you mean - the observations, *y*(*i*), are not exactly equal to *a* . *t*(i)^*b* . exp(*ct*(*i*)) (otherwise almost any 3 observations would give you the exact parameter values).

So the noise has to enter your model for *y* somehow. Is it additive? multiplicative, or something else? (Also important, but for other reasons: does its size change in some way as *t* changes, or not? Are the noise terms for different observations independent?)

If your actual model is  *y*(*i*) = *at*(*i*)^*b* . exp(*ct*(*i*))+ε(*i*), that's not linearizable.

If your actual model is *y*(*i*) = *at*(*i*)^*b* . exp(*ct*(*i*)) . ε(i), and ε(*i*)=exp(η(*i*)) for some (hopefully zero-mean) η(*i*), that is linearizable.

Taking the second form,

log(*y*(*i*)) = log(a) + b log(*t*(*i*)) + c *t*(*i*) + log(ε(*i*))

or

*y**(*i*) = a* + b.log(*t*(*i*)) + c.*t*(*i*) + η(*i*)

which is linear in the parameters *a** = log(*a*), *b* and *c*, and the error term η(*i*); so if you're prepared to make that sort of an assumption about the error you should be able to fit it with methods suitable for such linear models; you may wish in that case to ponder the parenthetical questions about the error term above which may affect how you model it.

Comment: thank you for your answer - you don't need to deal with my code, but I did revise it so that it is now reproducible.

Comment: Why does your code have `-c` in the function, where your mathematics has $c$? ($-c$ makes sense to me, to be honest; I'm more used to seeing that case and it fits better with the "scaled Gamma density notion")

Comment: Note that when you fit that nlme model, you're making assumptions about the form of the error.

Comment: A side-effect of migration here (which I didn't vote for on CV) is that the TeX-like mark-up for mathematics no longer works. Double pity: I still think this belongs on Cross Validated.

Comment: @Nick Thanks. I've made some changes to attempt to make it readable.